# How can I select the latest location of each taxi on mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I select the latest location of each taxi

I want to store the Taxi location in my sql script below , I tried to select each taxis latest location, if there are more than one location data for one of taxiId , the query should take the latest location

```
CREATE TABLE Taxi_Loc (
LocIds INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT,
TaxiId INT(10) NOT NULL,
Latitude FLOAT(10,6) ,
Longitude FLOAT(10,6),
CreateDate TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (LocIds),
FOREIGN KEY (TaxiId) REFERENCES Taxis(TaxiId)
)
```

My table is

```
LocId   TaxiId    Latitude    Longitude    CreatedDate
   2      2  -33.729752   150.836090      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   3      1  -33.812222   151.143707      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   4      1  -33.903557   151.237732      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   5      3  -33.949448   151.008591      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   6      2  -33.815521   151.026642      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   7      4  -33.796669   151.183609      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   8      3  -33.829525   150.873764      12/26/18 01:46 AM
   9      5  -33.944489   150.854706      12/26/18 01:46 AM
  10      4  -33.873882   151.177460      12/26/18 01:46 AM
  11      1  -33.737885   151.235260      12/26/18 04:26 PM
```

I want to get this result

```
 LocId  TaxiId  Latitude    Longitude   CreatedDate
   2    2   -33.729752  150.836090  12/26/18 01:46 AM
   3    1   -33.812222  151.143707  12/26/18 01:46 AM
   5    3   -33.949448  151.008591  12/26/18 01:46 AM
   7    4   -33.796669  151.183609  12/26/18 01:46 AM
   9    5   -33.944489  150.854706  12/26/18 01:46 AM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Taxi_Loc WHERE LocIds IN (SELECT MAX(LocIds) FROM Taxi_Loc GROUP BY TaxiId)
```

**Explanation:**

Following sub query helps to find relevant `LocIds`. This assumes latest `LocIds` have higher numbers.

> **SELECT MAX(LocIds) FROM Taxi_Loc GROUP BY TaxiId**